Unable to connect kafka broker running in docker container from my spring application
I was doing hands on in kafka and wrote a simple spring producer-consumer application. I created one docker-compose file to to start the zookeeper and kafka broker instance inside a container. I am using docker desktop in windows to start the container.
Here are sample files,
docker-compose.yaml
version: '2'
services:
  zookeeper:
    image: wurstmeister/zookeeper
    ports:
      - "2181:2181"
  kafka:
    image: wurstmeister/kafka
    ports:
      - "9092:9092"
    environment:
      KAFKA_ADVERTISED_HOST_NAME: 127.0.0.1
      KAFKA_ZOOKEEPER_CONNECT:  zookeeper:2181
      KAFKA_CREATE_TOPICS: "Topic1:1:3"

application.yaml
spring:
  kafka:
    consumer:
      auto-offset-reset: earliest
      bootstrap-servers: localhost:9092
      group:
        id: "myGroup"
      key-deserializer: org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringDeserializer
      value-deserializer: org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringDeserializer
    producer:
      bootstrap-servers: localhost:9092
      key-serializer: org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringSerializer
      value-serializer: org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringSerializer

Producer
package org.example.kafka;

import java.util.UUID;
import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;
import org.springframework.kafka.core.KafkaTemplate;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;

@Service
public class KafkaProducer {
  private KafkaTemplate<String, String> kafkaTemplate;

  private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(KafkaProducer.class);

  public KafkaProducer(KafkaTemplate<String, String> kafkaTemplate) {
    this.kafkaTemplate = kafkaTemplate;
  }

  public void sendMessage(String message) {
    logger.info(String.format("Message sent %s", message));
    kafkaTemplate.send("Topic1",UUID.randomUUID().toString(), message);

  }
}

Consumer
package org.example.kafka;

import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;
import org.springframework.kafka.annotation.KafkaListener;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;

@Service
public class KafkaConsumer {

  private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(KafkaConsumer.class);

  @KafkaListener(topics = "Topic1", groupId = "myGroup")
  public void getMessage(String message){
    logger.info("consumed message %s" , message);
  }
}

Server starts properly however when executing producer from a controller via api client it is giving this kind of logs
2024-08-18T11:21:31.556+05:30  INFO 23400 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.a.k.c.t.i.KafkaMetricsCollector        : initializing Kafka metrics collector
2024-08-18T11:21:31.566+05:30  INFO 23400 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.a.k.clients.producer.KafkaProducer     : [Producer clientId=producer-1] Instantiated an idempotent producer.
2024-08-18T11:21:31.596+05:30  INFO 23400 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.a.kafka.common.utils.AppInfoParser     : Kafka version: 3.7.1
2024-08-18T11:21:31.597+05:30  INFO 23400 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.a.kafka.common.utils.AppInfoParser     : Kafka commitId: e2494e6ffb89f828
2024-08-18T11:21:31.597+05:30  INFO 23400 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.a.kafka.common.utils.AppInfoParser     : Kafka startTimeMs: 1723960291596
2024-08-18T11:21:39.760+05:30  INFO 23400 --- [ntainer#0-0-C-1] org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient   : [Consumer clientId=consumer-myGroup-1, groupId=myGroup] Node -1 disconnected.
2024-08-18T11:21:39.765+05:30  INFO 23400 --- [ntainer#0-0-C-1] org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient   : [Consumer clientId=consumer-myGroup-1, groupId=myGroup] Cancelled in-flight API_VERSIONS request with correlation id 1 due to node -1 being disconnected (elapsed time since creation: 21014ms, elapsed time since send: 21014ms, request timeout: 30000ms)
2024-08-18T11:21:39.765+05:30  WARN 23400 --- [ntainer#0-0-C-1] org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient   : [Consumer clientId=consumer-myGroup-1, groupId=myGroup] Bootstrap broker localhost:9092 (id: -1 rack: null) disconnected
2024-08-18T11:21:52.631+05:30  INFO 23400 --- [ad | producer-1] org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient   : [Producer clientId=producer-1] Node -1 disconnected.
2024-08-18T11:21:52.631+05:30  INFO 23400 --- [ad | producer-1] org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient   : [Producer clientId=producer-1] Cancelled in-flight API_VERSIONS request with correlation id 0 due to node -1 being disconnected (elapsed time since creation: 21030ms, elapsed time since send: 21030ms, request timeout: 30000ms)
2024-08-18T11:21:52.632+05:30  WARN 23400 --- [ad | producer-1] org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient   : [Producer clientId=producer-1] Bootstrap broker localhost:9092 (id: -1 rack: null) disconnected
2024-08-18T11:22:00.896+05:30  INFO 23400 --- [ntainer#0-0-C-1] org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient   : [Consumer clientId=consumer-myGroup-1, groupId=myGroup] Node -1 disconnected.
2024-08-18T11:22:00.897+05:30  INFO 23400 --- [ntainer#0-0-C-1] org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient   : [Consumer clientId=consumer-myGroup-1, groupId=myGroup] Cancelled in-flight API_VERSIONS request with correlation id 2 due to node -1 being disconnected (elapsed time since creation: 21031ms, elapsed time since send: 21031ms, request timeout: 30000ms)
2024-08-18T11:22:00.897+05:30  WARN 23400 --- [ntainer#0-0-C-1] org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient   : [Consumer clientId=consumer-myGroup-1, groupId=myGroup] Bootstrap broker localhost:9092 (id: -1 rack: null) disconnected
2024-08-18T11:22:13.775+05:30  INFO 23400 --- [ad | producer-1] org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient   : [Producer clientId=producer-1] Node -1 disconnected.
2024-08-18T11:22:13.775+05:30  INFO 23400 --- [ad | producer-1] org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient   : [Producer clientId=producer-1] Cancelled in-flight API_VERSIONS request with correlation id 1 due to node -1 being disconnected (elapsed time since creation: 21040ms, elapsed time since send: 21040ms, request timeout: 30000ms)
2024-08-18T11:22:13.775+05:30  WARN 23400 --- [ad | producer-1] org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient   : [Producer clientId=producer-1] Bootstrap broker localhost:9092 (id: -1 rack: null) disconnected
2024-08-18T11:22:22.047+05:30  INFO 23400 --- [ntainer#0-0-C-1] org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient   : [Consumer clientId=consumer-myGroup-1, groupId=myGroup] Node -1 disconnected.
2024-08-18T11:22:22.047+05:30  INFO 23400 --- [ntainer#0-0-C-1] org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient   : [Consumer clientId=consumer-myGroup-1, groupId=myGroup] Cancelled in-flight API_VERSIONS request with correlation id 4 due to node -1 being disconnected (elapsed time since creation: 21033ms, elapsed time since send: 21033ms, request timeout: 30000ms)
2024-08-18T11:22:22.047+05:30  WARN 23400 --- [ntainer#0-0-C-1] org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient   : [Consumer clientId=consumer-myGroup-1, groupId=myGroup] Bootstrap broker localhost:9092 (id: -1 rack: null) disconnected
2024-08-18T11:22:31.605+05:30 ERROR 23400 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.k.support.LoggingProducerListener    : Exception thrown when sending a message with key='fe921b1d-e766-4190-b103-b31f0b5c7517' and payload='hello' to topic Topic1:

org.apache.kafka.common.errors.TimeoutException: Topic Topic1 not present in metadata after 60000 ms.

2024-08-18T11:22:31.613+05:30 ERROR 23400 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.a.c.c.C.[.[.[/].[dispatcherServlet]    : Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [] threw exception [Request processing failed: org.springframework.kafka.KafkaException: Send failed] with root cause

org.apache.kafka.common.errors.TimeoutException: Topic Topic1 not present in metadata after 60000 ms.

2024-08-18T11:22:34.981+05:30  INFO 23400 --- [ad | producer-1] org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient   : [Producer clientId=producer-1] Node -1 disconnected.

Please help me to resolve this. I have seen lot of tutorial all are doing same and works for them. I am using windows.

is the spring boot app running inside a container?

No it is outside containter

There are other similar questions. Try to add jackson-databind dependency in your spring application.
This seems to work for others.
